# OpenCV contour evolution

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I have a contour that I would like to "snap" to edges in an image. That is, some thing like Intelligent Scissors, but for the whole contour at the same. A user has provided a rough sketch of the outline of an object, and I'd like to clean it up by "pushing" each point on the contour to the nearest point in an edge image.

Does something like this exist in OpenCV?

Comment: I don't think OpenCV has a ready-made solution, but active snake models tend to work well for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model

Comment: A few images might help. Intelligent scissors use active contours, snakes, or the like. [OpenCV grabcut](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html#gsc.tab=0) should work well. You can try providing as _surely foreground_ your contour.

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic active contours using `cv::grabCut` as suggested. You choose the radius of attraction (how far from the original position the curve can evolve), and by using dilated and eroded images, you define the unknown region around the contour.

```
// cv::Mat img, mask; // contour on mask as filled polygon
if ( mask.size()!=img.size() )
    CV_Error(CV_StsError,"ERROR");
int R = 32; // radius of attraction
cv::Mat strel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(2*R+1,2*R+1) );
cv::Mat gc( mask.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(cv::GC_BGD) );
cv::Mat t;
cv::dilate( mask, t, strel );
gc.setTo( cv::GC_PR_BGD, t );
gc.setTo( cv::GC_PR_FGD, mask ); // 3
cv::erode( mask, t, strel );
gc.setTo( cv::GC_FGD, t ); // 1
cv::grabCut( img, gc, cv::Rect(), cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), 2 );
gc &= 0x1; // either foreground or probably foreground
gc *= 255; // so that you see it
```

What you may loose, is the topology of the contour. Some processing required there. Also, you cannot control the curvature or smoothness of the contour and it's not really contour evolution in sense.

Only if you are interested, ITK geodesic active contour might be what you are looking for http://www.itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1GeodesicActiveContourLevelSetImageFilter.html

Comment: I know what you mean by setting the unknown region around the contour (presumably I set this region between the eroded and dilated region to "probably foreground" in OpenCV terminology?), but what do you mean by the "radius of attraction" here?